# Delete named ranges used for chart series when deleting the chart

Tags: excel, vba, events, named-ranges

Is there any way to delete named ranges used in chart series when the chart is being deleted?
I use named ranges quite extensively in my daily work, also for charting. When I create charts I often name data ranges and THEN use them for chart series.

I am looking for a way to delete USED named ranges WHEN I delete the chart. I thought about chart "delete" event, but I cannot find any info about it (does it even exist???).
The second issue is how to determine which ranges have been used for chart series? Deleting the named ranges is easy, but how to actually determine, which ranges have been used in chart series?

All help is MUCH appreciated. Apologies but I cannot provide you with any code, as I have no idea how to set things up

Comment: What if the named range is used for something other than the chart series as well as the chart series?

Comment: @SmileyFtW It would be good if it is not deleted, but it CAN be deleted if it makes the code easier. My named ranges for general usage are called in "common sense" manner like "Input_discount_rate" while I tend to use more complicated names for charts to avoid this kind of duplication you are talking about... If you have any idea how to detect that duplication then it would just make the code more usable for the general purposes, not only my specific, at the moment needs.

Comment: @NareshBhople thanks for the link. It does not help me however. I do not know how to extract the name of named range used as value in my chart series. Or the other way around - how to loop through all named ranges (I know how to do that) and delete those ranges, which have specific prefix and are NOT used in charts. For example, to loop through all names starting with "Chart_" prefix and check if those names are used in charts. If not, then delete them. I would like to do that automatically as the chart itself is deleted (here chart.delete event comes into play), but I could live without it.

Comment: SO is here to help you fix a specific error (code won't run or gives unexpected result). Please write some code to do what you want and then when it doesn't do what you want post it here and explain the issue.

Comment: @SmileyFtW I am aware of the purpose of SO and I did not mean to be rude or something. I would be happy to provide code but I cannot find any info about chart delete event. That is why I decided to write here with a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code please. The USED named ranges cannot be extract directly. I used a trick to extract the ranges form `SeriesCollection` formula. Then compare them with names `RefersToRange.Address` and delete the matching name. It (now) returns a boolean value in case of match (only to see it in Immediate Window), but not necessary for your purpose. The code also delete the invalid names (having their reference lost).

Edited: I made some researches and I am afraid it is not possible to create a `BeforeDelete event`... It is an enumeration of events able to be created for a chart object, but this one is missing. I like to believe that I found a solution for your problem, respectively:

1. Create a class able to enable `BeforeRightClick` event. Name it `CChartClass` and write the next code:

   `Option Explicit`

   `Public WithEvents ChartEvent As Chart`

   `Private Sub ChartEvent_BeforeRightClick(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim msAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
      msAnswer = MsgBox("Do you like to delete the active chart and its involved Named ranges?" & vbCrLf & _
                       "  If yes, please press ""Yes"" button!", vbYesNo, "Chart deletion confirmation")
       If msAnswer <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
       Debug.Print ActiveChart.Name, ActiveChart.Parent.Name
       testDeleteNamesAndChart (ActiveChart.Parent.Name)
   End Sub`
2. Create another class able to deal with workbook and worksheet events, name it `CAppEvent` and copy the next code:

   `Option Explicit`

   `Public WithEvents EventApp As Excel.Application`

   `Private Sub EventApp_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
       Set_All_Charts
   End Sub`

   `Private Sub EventApp_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
       Reset_All_Charts
   End Sub`

   `Private Sub EventApp_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
       Set_All_Charts
   End Sub`

   `Private Sub EventApp_WorkbookDeactivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
       Reset_All_Charts
   End Sub`
3. Put the next code in a standard module (need to create a classes array in order to start the event for all existing sheet embedded charts):

`Option Explicit`

```
Dim clsAppEvent As New CAppEvent
Dim clsChartEvent As New CChartClass
Dim clsChartEvents() As New CChartClass

Sub InitializeAppEvents()
  Set clsAppEvent.EventApp = Application
  Set_All_Charts
End Sub

Sub TerminateAppEvents()
  Set clsAppEvent.EventApp = Nothing
  Reset_All_Charts
End Sub

Sub Set_All_Charts()
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim clsChartEvents(1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count)
        Dim chtObj As ChartObject, chtnum As Long

        chtnum = 1
        For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            Set clsChartEvents(chtnum).ChartEvent = chtObj.Chart
            chtnum = chtnum + 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Sub Reset_All_Charts()
    ' Disable events for all charts
    Dim chtnum As Long
    On Error Resume Next
     Set clsChartEvent.ChartEvent = Nothing
     For chtnum = 1 To UBound(clsChartEvents)
        Set clsChartEvents(chtnum).ChartEvent = Nothing
     Next ' chtnum
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub testDeleteNamesAndChart(strChName As String)
  Dim rng As Range, cht As Chart, sFormula As String
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, arrF As Variant, nRng As Range

  Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(strChName).Chart
  For j = 1 To cht.SeriesCollection.Count
    sFormula = cht.SeriesCollection(j).Formula: Debug.Print sFormula
    arrF = Split(sFormula, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrF) - 1
        If i = 0 Then
            Set nRng = Range(Split((Split(sFormula, ",")(i)), "(")(1))
        Else
            Set nRng = Range(Split(sFormula, ",")(i)) '(1)
        End If
        Debug.Print nRng.Address, matchName(nRng.Address)
    Next i

  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(strChName).Delete
End Sub

Private Function matchName(strN As String) As Boolean
   Dim Nm As Name, strTemp As String
   For Each Nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
     On Error Resume Next
        strTemp = Nm.RefersToRange.Address
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            Nm.Delete
        Else
            If strN = strTemp Then
                Nm.Delete
                matchName = True: Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
  Next
End Function
```

4. Use the next events code in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

   `Option Explicit`

   `Private Sub Workbook_Open()
           InitializeAppEvents
    End Sub`

   `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
           TerminateAppEvents
    End Sub`

Please confirm that it worked as you need

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I could not find a way to extract the names but your idea works great, thank you very much.
Perhaps you might be able to help with my second issue - do you know if there is any way to create some sort of "chart delete" event through VBA? [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/chart-object-events) I have found only this documentation and it says nothing about delete event. This event would help me a lot as I would be able to automate the whole process when I want to delete specific chart.

Comment: (Second comment) I have tried to do it with a dedicated class module but there is no built-in option to run a macro when a chart is deleted. Are you, or anyone reading this, aware of any way to run something automatically when a chart is being deleted?

Comment: @Rafał Kowalski: There is not such an event for a chart object and it is not so simple to create a custom event in VBA... Even if it will be, you have to create BeforeDelete event. Otherwise, you cannot obtain any information from a deleted object, even if you make it to raise such an event. But, I think, you can also transform my first sub in a function to be called after identifying of the chart object to be deleted. It will take the chart object like argument. And using it in this way there will not be necessary any event.

Comment: This is what I thought, sadly... Could you please elaborate a little bit on your function idea. If I understand it correctly, you would need to run this function manually to delete the chart and associated names, as without Delete/BeforeDelete events there is no way to automate it right?

Comment: @Rafał Kowalski: But if my code answers your question, it would be normal to tick the left side check box, making it accepted answer. In this way, somebody else asking for a similar problem will know that it worked. A delete event, anyhow, does not exist for the chart object...

Comment: @Rafał Kowalski: In order to ask your question you must specify how you intend to delete the charts. Do you intend to do that manually? I thought that you iterate between the existing sheet charts and select the ones to be deleted according to some criteria. When criteria are matched with one of the charts, a function will be called to previously delete the involved `Names` and then the chart itself.

Comment: I accepted your post as an answer. I am just looking for clarification and ideas for improvement :) I will be deleting the embedded charts manually. And when I delete the chart, I wanted to automatically delete USED names as well. That is why I thought about ChartDelete event.

Comment: Do you mean, it is not possible to find some criteria in order to automate the deletion process?

Comment: With your help, I can manage to delete the used ranges for my ActiveChart, but I am looking for a way to let Excel do it automatically when I delete the chart. Meaning, I want to delete the chart and have my "chart named ranges" disappear with it, instead of deleting those ranges first and then deleting blank chart afterward.

Comment: Anyhow, in order to create a chart event, you must find a specific chart to apply it! So, you also need some criteria in order to do that. I am afraid you cannot create such an event to be working for all chart objects of the workbook...

Comment: I am aware of that. And I am looking for a way to do it for ActiveChart. I want to select a chart manually in Excel and when it is activated, I delete it. When I delete it, I want to automatically delete associated named ranges :) That is why I though about chart event Delete.

Comment: I am afraid you did not get the point... Any event (custom or standard) acts if they have been created prior to deletion (in your case). How will you create such an event and alocate it to a specific chart without having some criteria to identify that specific chart? And, if you have criteria, no need of any event. You have the whole solution...

Comment: I see your point now... Well, the only idea I can think of right now is that when I delete the chart, the DeleteEvent is triggered and then: it loops through all named ranges and checks if this name is used in any one of the remaining charts. If not then delete it. But it would only work if named ranges used for charting had some kind of prefix attached (it should be checked). Otherwise, this procedure will delete all named ranges used for different purposes, not only charting. This way I think you would not have to use BeforeDelete event, as it would handle everything AFTER chart is deleted.